# Issue of creating PDF file in directory of Azure Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I have functionality for Reading excel file and creating a pdf on directory in Azure Server.

This functionality is working on local but not working on azure server(I have created folder in azure server).

so what would be issue regarding Directory access or something other and how I solve it.

Folder is available in main directory wwwroot>FolderName.

```
var filestream = new FileStream(pdfoutputpath + ".pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
                    return new FileStreamResult(filestream, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = outputfilename + ".pdf" };
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? what do you mean when you say it's not working?

Comment: Please define "Azure Server"

Comment: A blob storage may be more suitable to store the pdf files.